# tr:last not always grabbing last row

Tags: jquery

I'm experiencing a unique bug using the tr:last command in jquery.

I had a dynamic table based off .clone()'s of a template row.

When i add a row, I want to increment the row count to name the fields

But since i can also delete a row, the increment factor needs to look to the last row's id to see if the count is not the new rows var, but rather max+1.  (effectively, max+2 due to the clone row)

The gotchya i'm having is that it works every OTHER time...  it's very strange.

Here's a sample alert sequence of adding 3 rows.

max = 4 count = 5

max = 4 count = 6

max = 6 count = 7

So, finding max for 5 never actually takes place.

```
function addrow(table){
var className;
var count = $("#"+table+" tbody tr").length;
//since we have a th that server-side prints, no need to count++.  if th removed, count++ this.

//in case of rows removed, need to find last row and check its number...
var max = $("#"+table+" tbody tr:last").attr('id').split("_").pop();
alert('max='+max+'   count='+count);
if(parseInt(max)+2>count){
    count = max;
}

var $clone = $("#"+table+" tbody tr:first").clone();
$clone.attr({
        id: "dynrow_" +$('#'+table).attr("id")+"_"+ count.toString(),
    "class": "" , //remove template class
    style: "" // remove "display:none"
    });
$clone.find("input,select,textarea").each(function(){
    var xname = $(this).attr("name") + count.toString();
        $(this).attr({
            id: $(this).attr("id") + count.toString(),
            name: xname
        });     
    //populate fields that don't exist on page build by reading datacollector div with html5 data 
    $(this).val($("#datacollector").data(xname));
});

if(count%2==0){
    className="even";
}
else{
    className="odd";
}

$clone.find("td").each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("xcol")){
        className = className + ' xcol';
    }
        $(this).attr({
            'class': className
        });                 
});
$clone.find("label").each(function(){
        $(this).attr({
            "for": $(this).attr("for") + count.toString()
        });
});
$clone.find("a.removerow").each(function(){
        $(this).attr({
            id: $(this).attr("id") + count.toString()
        });
});
$("#"+table+" tbody").append($clone);

//update row counter
$("#initialrows_"+table).val(count.toString());
```

}

```
<input type="hidden" id="initialrows_table_aaa" name="initialrows_table_aaa" value="1">
<table id="table_aaa" class="dynrow">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!--template-->
    <tr class="template" id="template_aaa" style="display:none;">
        <td class="even"><label for="inp_16">a</label><input type="text" name="a_" id="inp_16" value=""></td>
        <td class="even"><label for="inp_17">b</label><select id="inp_17" name="b_">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="even"><label for="inp_18">c</label><select id="inp_18" name="c_">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<!--end template-->
</tbody>
```

working fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/briansol/5h4cM/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if (parseInt(max)+2>count){
    count = max;
}
```

So when you add a row, and `max = 4 count = 6`, `max + 2 = 6`, which isn't greater than `count (6)`, so `count` doesn't get incremented, so it adds another row with the same `id`.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h4cM/2/)

Comment: Right...  but max should never be 4 when count is 6.  it simply can't get to that spread.  If you view dom source, you'll see there's a row 5 when it reports a max of 4.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood something, it won't be. You're alerting the values of `max` and `count` before you're setting the new value of `count` or inserting the new row

Comment: good catch.  I plugged 1 in, and i'm still having issues once i delete a row.   The selects actually trigger each other and im getting dupe ID's so the first select populates the wrong 2nd select.

What i'm trying to do is name the new row either the next available count, or the last row +1.   maybe i should do max row +1 all the time and not care about the row counter as much.

Comment: When I do something like this I just have a counter, which I increment every time a new row is added. If rows are deleted the numbers won't be sequential, but you won't end up duplicating IDs

Comment: The delete is just a click listener to a $(#trid).remove() command.  it in itself is not the issue.  its once a delete has been made that isn't the LAST row, a new Add causes the issue because it takes on an id that is already in use.

I tried switching to always use the max,
if(isNaN(max)){
  alert('updating to 1');
  count = 1;
 }
 else {
  count++;
 }
 

and that also fails.

Comment: Using the external counter is a good idea, and i had thought about it.  But its making back end processing tough.

Comment: @briansol just use arrays for your form inputs, that'll make processing much easier.

Comment: If only I was using php...  That was the first thing i tried.  Unfortunately, only the first item comes in, not a list, to the back end scripting engine i'm using (a fairly one-off set up)

Comment: @briansol I think the only way you can do this would be to re-index all of the rows when the form is submitted, or when a row is removed. [Here's a simple example of the latter](http://jsfiddle.net/9nn2C/27/)

Comment: That is where i'm heading...  if el 3 comes out, 4 becomes 3, 5 becomes 4, and so on.   It's the only way to keep the front and back end indexes in line.